# Swap the value of two pointers atomically

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, race-condition

I've learnt that semaphore can act as an atomic lock that can perform two function: `down` and `up`.

Is there any way, to swap the `value` of two pointers atomically, avoiding race condition and deadlock.

I first came up with the 'solution', suppose both pointers has :

```cpp
Item a = { value = "A", lock = Semaphore(1) }
Item b = { value = "B", lock = Semaphore(1) }

void atomic_swap(Item* a, Item* b) {
    a->lock.down(); // acquire
    b->lock.down(); // acquire
    
    non_atomic_swap(&a.value, &b.value);

    b->lock.up(); // release
    a->lock.up(); // release
}
```

But if I am not wrong, it will result to deadlock if two `atomic_swap` is called using same pointers: *eg.*

```cpp
Item a = ...;
Item b = ...;
thread_start(atomic_swap, {&a, &b}); // start a thread running atomic_swap(&a, &b);
thread_start(atomic_swap, {&b, &a}); // start a thread running atomic_swap(&b, &a);
```

On the code above, if both call to `atomic_swap` arrive the first `down` simultaneously, the next `down` will block forever, which results to deadlock.

---

One of the solution I can think about to avoid deadlock is assign a 'group' to them, only item in the same group can perform `atomic_swap` safely (without deadlock):

```cpp
Group g = { lock = Semaphore(1) };
Item a = { value = "A", group = g };
Item b = { value = "B", group = g };

void atomic_swap(Item* a, Item* b) {
    // assume a->group == b->group

    a->group.down() // b->group.down()
    non_atomic_swap(&a.value, &b.value);
    a->group.up(); // b->group.up();
}
```

But this of course require every item to carry a `group`, and unrelated items might wait for the group because of other calls.

Is there any good way to perform the `atomic_swap` theoretically using semaphore?

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for a spinbuffer? There should be plenty on that for c++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::less` to compare the pointers to ensure that all users acquire the locks in the same order:

```
void atomic_swap(Item* a, Item* b) {
    std::less<Item *> cmp;

    if (cmp(a, b)) {
        a->lock.down();
        b->lock.down();
    } else {
        b->lock.down();
        a->lock.down(); }
    
    non_atomic_swap(&a->value, &b->value);

    b->lock.up(); // release
    a->lock.up(); // release
}
```

Comment: May also want to mention `std::lock` and its RAII wrapper `std::scoped_lock`.

Comment: I do kind of suspective in the first place before I tried on some more pairs eg. `(a, b)`, `(b, c)` and `(a, c)`, in the end I am convinced that it wouldn't results to deadlock.